# f is uniformly continuous if the restriction is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Given $f: [0, +\infty)$, suppose there exists $a > 0$ such that $\left.{f}\right|_{[0, a]}$ and $\left.{f}\right|_{[a, +\infty)}$ are uniformly continuous. Prove that f is uniformly continuous.

It seems obvious to me, but I couldn`t find a way to write it.

Thank you!

Comment: I tried to do this:

Suppose that f is not uniformly continuous. Then, there exists $\epsilon$ > 0 such that for every $\delta$ > 0 , there exists x, y $\in$ M such that $d(x, y) < \delta \implies  d(f(x), f(y)) \geq \epsilon. $ 

I would like to conclude that it is possible to take both x and y in [0, a] or [a $\infty$) and it would be absurd.

Comment: It's rare that you prove continuity, differentiability, or uniform continuity by contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Find $\delta_1>0$ so that for $x,y\in[0,a]$ and $|x-y|<\delta_1$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$, and similarly and similarly $\delta_2>0$ for $[a,+\infty)$.

Then choose $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$.

The only case that matters is when $x<a<y$ and $|x-y|<\delta$. This is why we chose $\epsilon/2$. I'll let you fill in that last detail.